# Serialized Dropdown Lists

Tags: html, angularjs

I am struggling with the task of serializing dropdown lists. I am building an app that lets you order items and than you can view the orders. So each order has a list of items assigned to it. I am using AngularJS 1.6.9. This is the html page :

```
<div ng-app="ShowOrdersApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="container">
            <br><br>
            <button ng-click="getOrders()"> Show Orders </button>
            <br><br>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th > Orders </th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in orderlist">

                    <td><label> No. {{x.id}} </label><br>
                        <label> Date and Time : {{x.timestamp}} </label><br>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-click="getOrderDetails(x.id)"> List of Items
                        <span class="caret"></span></button><br>


                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>

</div>
```

[image: This is what it looks ike]

On clicking the blue button I want it to show all the items assigned to particular order, but I have trouble creating the dropdown since number of orders may vary and number of items for each order may vary as well. How do I make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, do i understood correctly - you want to show `items` from  `List of items` in dropdown?
Try with this : 
HTML:

```
<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th > Orders </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">

                        <td><label> No. {{x.id}} </label><br>
                            <label> Date and Time : {{x.date}} </label><br>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ng-click="getOrderDetails(x.id)"> List of Items
                            <span class="caret"></span></button><br>
                             <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" ng-repeat="item in x">
                               <a class="dropdown-item" style="display: block" ng-repeat="y in item">{{y.name}}</a>
                            </div></div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LZ8TF0MumSGPOXqFAkLm?p=preview

Comment: It worked fine but I got the following error: https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=y%20in%20item&p1=string:1&p2=1                                                                                               Can be easily fixed by adding {ng-repeat="y in item track by $index" } Dziękuję !